# Handling .NET api response in Angular using NgRx

Tags: .net, angular, try-catch, ngrx

With following code i'm dispatching an action to login a user. Whenever bad credentials are filled in, my .NET backend sends back `NotFound()` (404 status code). I'm trying to handle this reponse by using try/catch block in my angular code but at this point i still see the 404 error in the console even if i use this try/catch block. How can I make sure that this HTTP error isn't logged?

**Angular**

```
try {
  this.store.dispatch(loginAction({ request }))
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error: " + error)
}
```

**.NET**

```
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResponse<String>>> Login(UserLoginDto request)
{
    var response = await _authRepo.Login(request.Username, request.Password);

    // Check the response
    if (!response.Success) return NotFound(response);
    return Ok(response);
}
```

**Console**

[image]

Comment: i looked at the Angular documentation to see whether dispatch raises/triggers an error and didn't see one. I didn't do a detail search; btw I don't think try/catch is the idiom to capture HTTP error code.

Comment: @MZM Do you know another way to not show the 404 error in the console?

Comment: remember everything coming back from the web server is in the response so parse the response or if (!response.Success) redirect to the front-page or do what's require by the spec. The question is whether you want this done on the client side when traditionally we've done this on the web server side by customizing 404 error page return (customize error page in centralized location) comes in handy when prod need immediate changes at 3:00AM.

Comment: @MZM I understand , but how can i determine/capture (client side) the error response if the try-catch block does not work? The problem is: backend sends back 404 because creds are invalid and i need to capture this on client side so that i don't see the error in console

Comment: here this Microsoft document provides detailed (with authentication) explanation and sample code on using Angular on the client with a .NET backend,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return `NoContent()` instead of `NotFound()` in the .NET API

We use `NotFound()` with the pages that not found, and use `NoContent()` as a search result.

The full description of all status:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=net-7.0

After this change we need to discus the possible empty result inside the effect instead of error.

Answer (score 0):

The `store.dispatch` method just sends the action to the registered reducers and effects. Surrounding the dispatch with a try catch does nothing (unless you dispatch an action without a type).
If you want to catch the 404, you need to do this in the effect.

See the docs https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#handling-errors for more info.

Comment: I understand and this is already the case in my code. If you look at my question, what i'm trying to figure out is how to remove that error in console, when `NotFound()` is send back to client. Everything related to the state on correct en incorrect response is all good and coverted. It is just that error in the console.

Comment: Oh ok @AntoBoy. In that case... that's how a browser behaves, you can disable this within the console settings. Look for the "Hide network" option to remove the logs, but this will just be for you.